# mongodb create database file automatically after certain period

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb Database generate files automatically after certain period as follow
Doc.0
Doc.1
Doc.2
Doc.3
Doc.4

but Doc.ns file never regenerate like above file

Comment: And your question is? And what about details, like version used, OS used, steps needed to reproduce? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what, if anything, you are specifying as a problem. This is expected behavior. MongoDB allocates new data files as the data grows. The .ns file, which stores namespace information, does not grow like data files, and shouldn't need to.

Comment: data file increase by double of previous file size.